# Brightness file is loosing permission after restart or wake up the PC from suspend

Tags: permissions

I have the following problem with the `brightness` file that loses its permission every time I restart the pc, or when I wake it from suspend mode. In order to be able to use the mouse and the scroll function in Polybar for the brightness module, this file must be owned by me. What is the solution to keep the file permissions after restart or wake up from suspend mode, so I don't have to use the command below all the time?

`sudo chown <user>:<groupuser> /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `udev` rule to change the group ownership and permissions.

Create a new rules file, e.g. `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-backlight.rules` and add the following content
to change the group to `video` and to add write permissions for this group:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", RUN+="/bin/chgrp video $sys$devpath/brightness", RUN+="/bin/chmod g+w $sys$devpath/brightness"
```

<sup>(This rule was copied from the [ArchWiki Backlight](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/backlight#ACPI) page.)</sup>

Then add all users who should be able to control the brightness to this group.